# Cache result in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular JS application I need to show user the result of the javascript function (heavyFunction in my example), which depends on user input, so I am using {{}} to show the result.

I need to show it only in certain conditions, so I am also invoking this function in ng-show and ng-class directives.

```
<span ng-show="heavyFunction() > 0" ng:class="{true:'red', false:'blue'}[heavyFunction() > 5]"> {{heavyFunction()}} </span>
```

The problem is that I am invoking function three time, instead of one time. 
What is the best practice in Angular JS to invoke this function only once?

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/9r5AlA3RbtZLseOCOzPX?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this in your example is to use `ngChange`.
On input value change, bind a function that gets triggered, which call the heavy function.

```
$scope.numberChanged = function() {
    $scope.heavyFunction();
};
```

Then in html, bind the ng change:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="a" ng-change="numberChanged()"></input>
<input type="number" ng-model="b" ng-change="numberChanged()"></input>
```

Then make sure that the heavy function is caching the result:

```
$scope.heavyFunction = function() {
    $scope.result = $scope.a + $scope.b;
};
```

And in the ui, changes classes and display output by binding the the cached `result`:

```
<p>a + b:</p> <span ng-show="result > 0" ng:class="{true:'red', false:'blue'}[result > 5]"> {{result}} </span>
```

On a side not, if you have a function that has to be executed by html by only once, you can make use of `one time binding` built into angularJs. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding

Comment: Chanthu, thanks, but this solution will require to have ng-change on every element, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`ngBind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)**

Like this

```
ng-bind="total=heavyFunction()"
```

HTML

```
<p>a + b:</p> <span ng-bind="total=heavyFunction()" ng-show="total > 0" ng-class="{true:'red', false:'blue'}[total > 5]"> {{total}} </span>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/e97WLTc4BUIF8vxFWFwP?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for sharing Anik! This works, just for some reason heavy still invokes two time, but at least not 6 times as it was before!